# Persisting a temporal collection with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, temporal, temporal-database

I need to persist with JPA a **collection of a collection which changes temporally**.

Suppose I have a `Customer` making **multiple** `Orders` at a time, I'd need operations like:

```
Customer c = new Customer();
Set<Order> o = new Set<Order>();
Instant validFrom = now(); // something similar
Instant validTo = infinity(); // something similar
c.setOrders(validFrom, validTo, o);
```

with structures like

```
class TemporalSet<V>  {
...
    Instant validFrom;
    Instant validTo;
    Set<V> value;
}
```

and with Customer being

```
class Customer {

    Collection<TemporalSet<Order>> orders;
}
```

**I need to persist the `orders` field with JPA**, and I don't know how to do this.

In the past, when I asked how to handle temporal **properties**,  someone suggested me to give a look at the [DaoFusion framework](http://opensource.anasoft.com/daofusion-site/), which  includes the [Bitemporal Pattern by Erwin Vervaet](https://github.com/klr8/bitemporal), but as far as I understand, one can use it only to map bitemporal **properties** (not collections), as the mapping is a OneToMany, so the second side must be a single value.

The example shown in the Bitemporal pattern section of DaoFusion shows indeed an example with Customer and Orders which is similar to mine, but as far as I understand one can only have one order at a time, not a collection of orders.

Did I correctly understand that code?

How would one handle a temporal collection with JPA? (I need only valid time, I don't need a bitemporal solution with record time)

edit: the question has been updated adding the fields of Customer and of TemporalSet

Comment: You said `Set<Order>` and then tried to add `Time` to it. The time (really probably an `Instant`) should be a property (column) on the `Order`.

Comment: I agree with you, Order should have two columns validFrom and validTo which describe the validity of the order. However, I told Customer to set the valid time on the orders with setOrders, as I think it's more practical. Then Customer should set somehow that time on the orders

Comment: TBH it's quite difficult to understand what exactly the problem you're trying to solve is. Can't the `c.setOrders(Instant, Set<Orders>)` method simply iterate over all the elements in the set, assigning the time to each `Order`, and then add the elements of that set to `Customer.orders`? Please explain why you think that's not a viable solution in your case

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you suggest a Customer has a single Set of Orders, but I need a Collection of Sets of Orders, and need to persist that type of structure with JPA. I will update my question